# Ghosting in Java when using JMenuBar, JColorChooser and a paint method

Tags: java, swing

I am very new to java, and I am trying to practice some of the things I have learned by making a simple paint application. I tried using JMenubar to add a menu to my program which calls JColorChooser to let the user choose the colour of the paint brush. However there is a glitch where when clicking on the menu, a non functional copy of it is drawn on my JPanel. And after selecting a colour, a copy of the ColorChooser menu is drawn on my JPanel.

my code consists of 3 files, the first one containing the main class which does nothing but call my childclass of JFrame which I called PaintApp.

Then the second file contains the PaintApp class,

public class PaintApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

```
Canvas canvas;

JMenuBar menuBar;

JMenu settingsMenu;

JMenuItem brushColour;
JMenuItem brushSize;
JMenuItem clearItem;

PaintApp(){
    
    canvas = new Canvas();
    
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    
    settingsMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
    
    brushColour = new JMenuItem("Brush Colour");
    brushSize = new JMenuItem("Brush Size");
    clearItem = new JMenuItem("Clear Canvas");
    
    brushColour.addActionListener(this);
    brushSize.addActionListener(this);
    clearItem.addActionListener(this);
    
    settingsMenu.add(brushColour);
    settingsMenu.add(brushSize);
    settingsMenu.add(clearItem);
    
    menuBar.add(settingsMenu);
    
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.add(canvas);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    if(e.getSource()==brushColour) {
        
        Color colour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a Colour", Color.black);
        
        canvas.setColour(colour);
        
    }
    
    if(e.getSource()==brushSize) {
        
    }
    
    if(e.getSource()==clearItem) {
        canvas.removeAll();
        canvas.repaint();
    }
    
}
```

}

which is where the code for JFrame, ColorChooser, and JMenuBar is, and then my 3rd file contains my Canvas class which is where the code for the JPanel is, as well as the mouse listener and paint method which allow the program to paint on screen where the mouse points.

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel{

Point brushStart = new Point();
Point brushEnd = new Point();

Color brushColour;


Canvas(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    
    ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener();
    DragListener dragListener = new DragListener();
    this.addMouseListener(clickListener);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(dragListener);
    brushColour = new Color(0,0,0);
    
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    g2D.setPaint(brushColour);
    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    g2D.drawLine((int)brushStart.getX(), (int)brushStart.getY(), (int)brushEnd.getX(), (int)brushEnd.getY());
    
}

public void setColour(Color color) {
    brushColour = color;
}


private class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter{
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        brushStart = e.getPoint();
        brushEnd = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
    
}

private class DragListener extends MouseMotionAdapter{
    
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        
        brushStart = brushEnd;
        brushEnd = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
    
}
```

}

For some reason this is resulting in this ghosting behaviour. [image]

the black and purple lines were drawn by me to show that you can draw over the ghosted image, and that the ghosted image abstructs previous drawings.

When the program first runs the window appears blank at first with only the settings menu visible and nothing drawn on screen. the moment you drawn anything anywhere, or click the settings menu, a ghost of the settings menu appears underneath it. Then if you try to enter the colour selection menu, and select a colour, once you exit the menu, a ghost of the menu appears in the panel.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section. You'll want to use the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel`.  The [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson will show you how.  `Canvas` is the name of an AWT class and is confusing.

Comment: Yes, as @GilbertLeBlanc said, override `paintComponent` and make a call to `super.paintComponent` as your first line

Comment: Some one broke the paint chain. Overriding a method normally means you either need to delegate it's pre-existing functionality back to the `super` method or take over it's functionality, neither of which you have done. GilbertLeBlanc comment is the correct corse of action